# Make GNOME keyboard shortcuts available on lockscreen (login screen )

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, login-screen, lock-screen

I configured some usefull custom keyboard shortcut via gnome built-in shortcut feature (for example a keyboard shortcut for quick suspending ).
However, when I lock my computer, they are not available anymore.

How to make keyboard shortcut availble on lockscreen (also called login screen ) ?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04, GNOME Shell 3.36.9

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. When you lock your computer, it is... well, locked. Unlock your computer first to control it. Lock it if you want to remove the ability that someone (including yourself) controls it.

Comment: Well, then I would like to change the "design". Does that mean I have to compile my own version of gnome ? Any hints about that ?

Comment: Yes, that means you may need to reprogram the application. However, it may be possible to define shortcut keys for the gdm user, which probably is the user "active" on the login screen. Anyway, better wait: a better answer than mine may come around.